# Different AndroidManifest.template.xml for Debug and Release in delphi embarcadero

Tags: android, delphi, manifest

For publishing apps, Google play requires in manifest file:

```
android:debuggable="false"
```

In delphi is template for android (AndroidManifest.template.xml):

```
debuggable="%debuggable%"
```

Is it possible to set **%debuggable%** variable in some project configuration, to have different values for Release and different for Debug? (true/false)
 Or can we have different templates for Release and different for Debug?

Answer (score 0):

When you left click on the "Build Configurations" in Project manager, double click on the "Release" Gear, and on "Target Platforms" Click on "Android>Configuration" and double click on "Application Store".